# Finding the change of variables when they are not specified

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I am asked to solve this integral over the area D that lies in the first octant $(x ≥ 0) (y≥0)$. Where D is the area between the two ellipsoids $4x^2 + y^2 = 16$ and $4x^2 + y^2 = 1$. I think using change of variables will help me solve this integral, however I do not know how to do so. I have tried using the trigonometric property $\sin^2(θ) + \cos^2(θ) = 1$, where u is r and v is θ.
$$\iint \frac {x}{4x^2+y^2}dA$$

Comment: I personally would find the coordinates where the ellipsoids meet, then rearrange the equations so that you have only $x$ as a variable and integrate them normally. This only uses basic univariate calculus so it would be more work, but might make more sense depending on your strengths and background.

Comment: @BillWallis The ellipses don’t meet. They are homothetic and concentric.

Comment: You could certainly convert to polar coordinates, but I think I’d shrink the $y$-direction by a factor of two first so that the integration is over a quarter-annulus.

Answer (score 2):

Try the substitution, $u=x$ and $v= 4x^2 + y^2.$

The region of integration transforms to a rectangle, $ u\in [1/2,2],$ and $v\in [1,16].$

Do not forget your Jacobean for $dA$

Comment: @Mohammed Riazi Kermani I tried this, but the integral you get then is impossible for me to solve.

Comment: What is the integral ?

Comment: I dont think i calculated the Jacobi correctly. If you set u and v as you have showed i get a jacobi containing x's and y's..

Comment: You need to find the inverse of the matrix to get it in terms of u and v

Comment: Hmm, i get 1/2y.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Inverting the matrix still gives you something that’s populated with $x$’s and $y$’s, not $u$’s and $v$’s.

Comment: You just need to invert  the determinant of the  Jacobian matrix and  find x and y in terms of u and v.  to  have  your integral in terms of u and v.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to polar coordinates is a reasonable idea, but you would do better by choosing a substitution that follows the boundaries of the region. The two ellipses are homothetic and concentric, so something like $x = r\cos\theta$, $y=2r\cos\theta$ for $\frac12\le r\le2$, $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$ with Jacobian determinant $2r$ looks promising. This gives you a parameterization of the inner and outer ellipses for $r=\frac12$ and $r=2$, respectively, and conveniently the denominator of the original integrand transforms into a multiple of $r$. The integration is then over a rectangle in $(r,\theta)$-space.